# Ensuring future of recursive function in aiohttp/asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm having an issue with a recursive function not properly being called within an event loop. I have the following:

```
async def get_response(session, url, attempt=0):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            return await response.json()
        elif attempt < 3:
            # This never gets called, a coroutine is returned
            return get_response(session, url, attempt + 1)
        else:
            return None

async def main(loop):
    output = []
    urls = ["https://httpbin.org/json"]
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_response(session, url)))
        for future in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
            output.append(future)
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    output = loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

The problem arises in `get_response` where if `attempt < 3` it won't actually run the function again. **The above code will work just fine since `https://httpbin.org/json` will return a 200 code.** Correct me if I'm wrong (because I probably am) but I'm thinking that since that iteration of the function isn't in the list of tasks in `main` then it won't actually run? What I get in return when I debug is an actual coroutine object rather than `None` as I had intended.

What is the proper way to ensure a recursive function within a `future` will be called again if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `get_response` is async, you need to await it when calling it, even when doing so from itself. So, you need to change:

```py
            return get_response(session, url, attempt + 1)
```

to:

```py
            return await get_response(session, url, attempt + 1)
```